# PHPSpreadSheet Writer Xlx doesn't work in PHP version 7.0

Tags: php, export-to-excel, temporary-files, phpspreadsheet

So I made this program to export data from database into excel format with PHP language and library called PHPSpreadsheet. In localhost the program works fine. But in online server the program is not working. Does this have issue with PHP version, cause in my localhost, it's PHP 7.2 but in online server is 7.0.

> Is there any other library for export excel with PHP version 7.0? I have tried PHPExcel but they said its deprecated for php 7.x

```
<?php
  require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
  require_once('../../connection.php');
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
  use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

  // other code

  // export excel
  $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Pusdiklat - ".$data_diklat->nama.".xls");
  $writer->save("php://output");

  // display error
  ini_set('display_errors','1');
  ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)
?>
```

I have tried to display the error and the export worked but when I opened the excel it shows error. Here is the error:

> **Warning**:  ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary
>   file: No such file or directory in
>   **/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/data/daftar_diklat/excel/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php**
>   on line **409**
>
> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: Could not close zip file
>   php://output. in
>   /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/data/daftar_diklat/excel/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php:410
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/data/daftar_diklat/excel/export_pusdiklat.php(139):
>   PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx->save('php://output')
>       #1 {main}
>         thrown in **/home/admin/web/domain.com/public_html/admin/data/daftar_diklat/excel/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php**
>   on line **410**

And this is my server:

```
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you have error reporting enabled? Turn on all error reporting so you will see any errors that might be happening. `ini_set('display_errors','1');ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');error_reporting(E_ALL);mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your answer sir. I have updated the question, maybe you can help me with this problem?.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of PHPSpreadsheet and consider updating you version of PHP since 7.0 is out of support. If there is anything related to PHPSpreadsheet in the area of your code where you say `// other code` please add it.

Answer (score 2):

The support of PHP 7.0 was dropped at Version 1.9.0.